# Saving multipart form data into mongo with Node, Mongoose and Express 4

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've seen allot of questions but no simple answer for this simple issue:

I have a form with few fields and 2 attachments. I want them all to be saved into a Mongo
document (without GridFS and without local filesytem). I am using connect-busboy for parsing the body.

How to I process the request to extract all the fields and the attachments and persist them into my model?

```
var model requrie ('../models/model);
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var modelData = {}
    req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {

        file.on('data', function(data) {

            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');
        });
        file.on('end', function() {
            Here I want to get the file into the model before saving, right?
        });
    });
    req.busboy.on('field', function(key, value, keyTruncated, valueTruncated) {
        switch (key) {
            case 'title':
                model.title = value;
                break;
             // Other fields parsing here...

        }
    });

    req.busboy.on('finish', function() {
        debugger
        var model = new Model(modelData);
        model.save(function(err) {

            res.end();
        })
        console.log('Done parsing form!');

    })
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
})
```

Thank you

Comment: Please show what code you have so far and what you've attempted to do.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the question with code, but I was also hoping for tuotrials or documentation which I couldn't find